How to effectively use Angular signals inputs/effects with reactive forms
In the Angular documentation, I see this:

State changes are state changes of the component internal state or state changes by signals?
I'm having trouble by setting forms values with Angular using inputs signals.
I mean, I could not find any good way to create a form with initial values using signals input. Since at the declaration time, we still don't have access to inputs. So I created the form empty and add an effect that, if receive initial values it would patch those values to the form.
But I really would like to initialize the form with those values already.
I created a codesandbox with the exact scenario:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/signals-forms-wfpl5x
I would like to see how are you dealing with this and get some feedback on the approach I'm using.

Not sure why you're not setting during onInit like that:
import { Component, OnInit, effect, input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.template.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  initialValues = input.required<{ name: string }>();
  form!: FormGroup<{name: <FormControl<string>}>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.initialValues().name),
    });
  }
}

An other way is to create form based on input signal, using computed, but not effect. But this is going to reset you form each time initialValues input will be updated.
import { Component, OnInit, computed, effect, input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.template.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
})
export class FormComponent {
  initialValues = input.required<{ name: string }>();
  form = computed(
    () =>
      new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(this.initialValues().name),
      })
  );
}


It is a possible solution, thanks for that.  I just have 3 points about it:
1 - Using type assertion, which im not a fan of.
2 - You dont have the form typed correctly, you would have to create type, so we are loosing some type assertions
3 - I may be overthinking, from my understood i think that signals would replace the components life cycle, just like it happended with React hooks. So i think we should have some altenative to it.


You may not like it but in this case it's removing a warning which is only valid between construct and init time, and nothing happens in this case here, so the warning is useless. 2. I've updated the typing but this was not the point of the question and you could have done it yourself 3. I don't think so, especially when using external libraries. They even added more lifecycle hooks in angular 17, see https://blog.angular.dev/introducing-angular-v17-4d7033312e4b


Thanks again. Yes, the form as a computed works well, already tried it. But i don’t really know if it is a good choice. Somehow it seems signals and forms are not working very well together, or angular doc is not very clear os some points. Again, thanks for the ideas.
